# Reliable Actors behavior if it takes too many operations

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am new in Microsoft Azure Service Fabric. Lets pretend I have a kind of social network hosted in SF. Each users are Actors in this system. Then some of them become popular. I mean there a lot of people viewing one popular guy in that case many input write-operations for his actor increasing a views counter for example. It means load goes up on current "popular" actor and he must handle all requests and do not die. My questions are:

1. Where and how presented all requests to this "popular" actor?
2. Is it a queue for requests? And if it is, what happens with this queue if the actor was down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The popular actor will become a bottleneck. Actors are single threaded so it will only be able to handle one request at a time. Use Reliable Services directly if you need to handle concurrent requests to a single user.

Messages sent to an actor are queued but not reliably. If the actor fails over to another node, its queue is lost.

For more info, see the section on concurrency here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-actors-introduction/

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand you. You said use Reliable Services directly if I need to handle requests to a signle user. But that exactly what  my aim is. I have the API Gateway stateless service. It proxy the request (get user information) to the stateful micro service serving all users in the app. And all users presented as actors. Does you suggestion means that I need to store all users directly inside my stateful Reliable Services and do not present them as Actors?

Comment: there is a good article https://acom-swtest-2.azurewebsites.net/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-actors-pattern-distributed-networks-and-graphs/?rnd=1 and I am trying to get the solution. It uses the same model as I described below. What did I miss then?

Answer (score 1):

I would consider breaking the reads and writes into different actors. This way the reads on the "popular" actor will never be blocked while it's performing a write operation. Also, if you're looking to queue anything, it sounds like you'd want the write requests queued rather than any read requests (if that wasn't already your plan).

As for queuing, if you are using an Azure Storage Queue, a poller can pluck messages off the queue and for any unexpected results or errors, you may consider an error or poison queue.

Comment: I am not sure it is a correct approach. I mean, for instance, is it acceptable to give possibility for million of users make read operations from one "popular" actor?

Answer (score 0):

When we plan to use Azure Storage Queue, we may consider using the Cloud Design Pattern CQRS (Command Query Responsibility Segregation). This way we are least bothered about the Actor and as we design better thing will be just fine. Let's say the Actor is down the queue is still holding the value and when it is up again, this will be processed. While it is getting processed if the Actor is crashed, it may be half cooked. So we will not delete the Queue message immediately, rather we will make it invisible for certain period. Only delete the Queue Message once it is processed successfully.

You can Auto scale the Service Fabric Cluster to handle more load as well.